# Unmount drive from emergency mode

Tags: automount

I am running Ubuntu 18.10. I tried reformatting my secondary HDD (Ubuntu is on an SSD) to ext4 and changed the /etc/fstab file to automount the drive on startup.

I must have done something wrong because now I can only boot into emergency mode.

By my logic the problem would be solved If I just unmounted the HDD and edited the fstab file of which I made a backup a while ago.

The problem is that I have no idea how to do that from emergency mode. None of the usual commands work.

EDIT2:
I just booted via USB-Stick and this is the (i guess faulty) fstab file:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=5ece23e7-beea-431d-9960-4ef8f83df532 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0D53-953B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

# 1TB DATA HDD:
7264c768-09ca-4e0e-aeb7-018a3a25badb /media/DATA    ext4    defaults    0   0
```

Comment: Could you post your fstab config, hard to say what you have done wrong if not know what you have done.

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to unmount a drive in order to change its fstab entry?

Comment: Well my logic isn't flawless. Anyways, I booted from a USB stick an can access the fstab file. Is it safe to just remove the line? I will update my post in a second.

Comment: ... what you **will** need to do however is remount the drive on which the fstab file is located with rw enabled e.g. `mount -o remount,rw /`

Comment: @steeldriver that won't work if they're booted to a Ubuntu Live USB :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean `Recovery Mode`, and you can get to the `#` prompt, then type:

`sudo mount -o rw,remount /` # remount the disk rw

`cd /etc` # change directory

`sudo pico fstab` # to edit existing fstab

or, if you wish to restore your backup fstab:

`sudo mv fstab fstab.bad` # rename existing file, for safety

`sudo cp fstab.backup fstab` # restore backup fstab, use your own name

If you can't do any of this, then you'll have to boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, mount the HDD by using the `Files` (Nautilus) application, click on the HDD in the left pane, navigate to the /etc directory on the HDD, edit fstab, etc.

**Update #1:**

Make sure that `/media/DATA` mount point exists.

Change this line in fstab:

```
7264c768-09ca-4e0e-aeb7-018a3a25badb /media/DATA    ext4    defaults    0   0
```

to this:

```
UUID=7264c768-09ca-4e0e-aeb7-018a3a25badb /media/DATA    ext4    defaults,nofail    0   2
```

Comment: And yes folks... I used `sudo`... as some commands **still** require it, even in recovery mode...

Comment: Wait, did I just accidentally remove the UUID= ? That's embarrassing. Holy crap.

Comment: Thanks man, that fixed it. I feel stupid now. Have a good day.

Comment: @EVARATE change the last `0 0` to `0 2` so the drive will get checked at boot time, and add `nofail`, so the system will still boot if this drive is not available.